# Restricting access to "admin" panel for a website?

Tags: security, web, authentication

How can i restrict access to the admin/ section of my website? I can't limit it by IP address because we need to sometimes access the admin/ section from remote client locations (when giving a demo, etc).

there is of course, an admin username/password - but what else can i do?

Comment: Why is admin username/password not suitable or sufficient?

Comment: looking for more - dont even want to expose my application to unauthorized users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most applications just use a username/password for access control, and that's generally sufficient.  Some that require extra security use two-factor authentication, which might mean using a token that you carry with you (e.g. a device that generates a token that's kept in sync with a server) or a token that is sent to you (e.g. the system sends a text message to your phone with a token that you have to type in in addition to your password).

An easier option is to authenticate using a client certificate; you can carry the cert around with you on a thumb drive in case you're at a remote location (just remember to remove the certificate from the remote machine when you're done).

Here's a [nice write-up on client certificate authentication](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500).

Another option is to only allow connections from your local network, and then use VPN to join a remote machine to a local network.

Comment: hi @JacobM - is there a webservice that can generate and send a text messaage on demand?
i coudld use that for sending a secret password to the admin

Comment: There are a few -- http://www.twilio.com/ is one, http://www.clickatell.com/index_b.php is another -- but also many providers allow you to send an email to a special address and have that show up as a text message.  The email approach might be less secure, of course.

Answer (score 0):

if the admin interface is in an seperate folder, you can use .htaccess and http auth. the same can be done using e.g. rails to restrict access to certain routes (controllers).